# Insert is not happening in Merge where update is happening

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `FlowTrack`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FlowTrack]
(
    [RowID] [tinyint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ApplicationNo] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [StatusID] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [UpdateType] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Sample data:

```
RowID   ApplicationNo   StatusID    UpdateType  CreatedDate CreatedBy
1   BPS/ANA/MO/7/0146215    1   3   2015-06-17 12:59:56.387 Tests
2   BPS/BHI/20/0164615  1   3   2015-06-17 12:57:57.727 Tester
3   BPS/BHI/6/0204815   1   3   2015-06-17 12:57:57.727 Tester
```

My procedure :

```
ALTER procedure Flowtrack
   (@APPNO  varchar(50),
    @vc_status CHAR(1),
    @CreatedBy varchar(50) )
AS 
BEGIN 
    MERGE INTO [dbo].Flowtrack AS target
    USING (SELECT ApplicationNo, StatusID 
           FROM Flowtrack 
           WHERE ApplicationNo = @APPNO AND [StatusID] = @vc_status) AS source
        ON target.ApplicationNo = Source.ApplicationNo

    WHEN MATCHED THEN
       UPDATE 
          SET 
             target.ApplicationNo = source.ApplicationNo,
             target.StatusID = source.StatusID,
             target.UpdateType = 3,
             target.CreatedDate = getdate(),
             target.CreatedBy = @CreatedBy

    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
       INSERT
           ([ApplicationNo], [StatusID], [UpdateType],
            [CreatedDate], [CreatedBy])
       VALUES (source.ApplicationNo, source.StatusID, 3,
               getdate(), @CreatedBy);
end
```

When I'm doing update it is updating

```
EXEC Flowtrack 'BPS/ANA/MO/7/0146215',3,'Tests'
```

but when trying to insert, it is not inserting a new record

I'm unable to find out why it is not inserting

To insert new application no

```
EXEC Flowtrack 'BPS/ANA/MO/7',3,'Test'
```

Comment: your stored procedure takes 3 parameters, you are sending 4

Comment: my bad only 3 parameters i'm removing that passing parameter @t-clausen.dk

Comment: `source.StatusID` won't exist if the record isn't matched

Comment: In general, if the `target` table appears inside the `using` clause, there's some mis-thinking going on. Why are you selecting from the `FlowTrack` table there?

Comment: i will remove that statusid in and condition please check edited question @StuartLC

Comment: i'm trying to match with same table flow track to check whether record exists just updata else insert with in the same table @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: But the general form of merge is `MERGE <target> USING <some other data> ON <how the source data relates to the target>`. You generally shouldn't be trying to pull data *from* the target to form the `<some other data>` bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
MERGE INTO [dbo].Flowtrack AS target
USING (SELECT ApplicationNo, StatusID 
       FROM Flowtrack 
       WHERE ApplicationNo = @APPNO AND [StatusID] = @vc_status) AS source
    ON target.ApplicationNo = Source.ApplicationNo
    AND target.StatusID = Source.StatusID
```

The problem is when you pass new `AppNo`, then `source` is empty and there is nothing to insert.

Change to:

```
MERGE INTO [dbo].Flowtrack AS target
USING (SELECT ApplicationNo, StatusID 
       FROM (VALUES(@APPNO, @vc_status, @CreatedBy)) t(ApplicationNo, StatusID , CreatedBy)
      ) AS source
    ON target.ApplicationNo = Source.ApplicationNo
    AND target.StatusID = Source.StatusID
```

Comment: let me implement in my code basing on that i will ask you

Comment: why you bringing the input parameters inside the Merge Statement and why it is working for Update not for Insert @Giorgi Nakeuri

Comment: it worked fantastic for me but why merge is not working for inserting why we need to pass parameters inside the merge statement in source .can you explain ???

Comment: Ok. In merge statement you have target and source. You are merging rows from source to target. If there is row in sorce which is in target as well then you update the target. When you have row in source wich has no corresponding row in target you are inserting that row from source to target. Now in your solution int source part you where selecting from table FlowTrack. Now when you pass existing appno then source was selecting that row and thus update worked. When you passed new app no you selected 0 row from FlowTrack in source part, thus your source was empty and there was nothing to merge.

Comment: absolutely stunning explanation you cleared my doubts..thanks a ton